# How to turn off tensorflow error message in wsl2

Tags: tensorflow, wsl-2

When running tensor flow, I receive a message about "unable to open file to read NUMA node". I would like to not have this message appear.

The full text is:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:966] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:00.0/numa_node

Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
```

[image: CLICK TO SEE MESSAGE PICTURE]

I am running in the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The message in your question, *"wsl2 how to turn off tensorflow notification"* does not seem to appear in your screenshot at all that I can see.  Was that an erroneous paste, perhaps?  It might also be useful to provide more details on your system - What versions of Windows, WSL, etc. are you running?  What GPU?  Can you provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Your question needs quite a bit more information before it's likely that anyone can answer it for you.  I would recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), along with [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) (especially the part about the "Golden Rule", and the [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).  Thanks!